# how do i add a domain in development for recaptcha and dotenv gem with rails using subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

For subdomains in development I add to my /etc/hosts file `127.0.0.1    blog.mydomain.lh` and then I can access it at http://blog.mydomain.lh:3000 but I get an error from recaptcha that the site key doesn't match My .env file which is part of the dotenv configuration only has one RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY and one RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY I can add blog.mydomain.lh on the google recaptcha console but how am I going to add a site to the .env file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a site in .env, you just need to add it in recapcha console. Please also check adding your domain to `application.rb` will help. (don't forget to restart server). If that does not work, try using tunnelling services like ngrok and clouldflare tunnels and see if that works.